# how to join 2 csv files in neo4j on a common column?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have one users.csv file like:

```
user_id | location
1       | India
2       | Germany
3       | canada
```

order.csv

```
order_id | user_id | product
11        | 1      | Chicken
12        | 1      | Beetroot
11        | 1      | Spinach
13        | 2      | Potato
14        | 2      | Banana
```

I want to join both the csv file on user_id. I know how to do this in SQL but how do we perform this in Neo4j?
I tried something like:

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///sample_orders.csv' AS order_row with order_row where  order_row.product is not null 

merge(o:order_id {Name:order_row.order_id}) 

merge(t:order_ts{Name:order_row.order_ts}) 

merge(u:user_id{Name:order_row.user_id}) 

merge(p:product{Name:order_row.product})  

merge(n) - [:TO {x:order_row.order_id}]->(o)
```

how do we do this?

```
orders.merge(users, on='user_id', how='left') in neo4j ?
```

Comment: The query you are using and the queries you have shown have different columns?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two LOAD queries, each one with one of the two csv files. Just make sure with each LOAD that you are merging on the same user node.

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///users.csv' AS row 
merge(u:user_id{Name:row.user_id})
```

This will create your users.

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///orders.csv' AS row 
merge(u:user_id{Name:row.user_id}) 
yada yada
```

This will merge on existing users and add whatever else data is in orders.